# Can I get the `arguments` objects if one of the arguments is called "arguments"?

Tags: javascript

The following code will print `1`:

```
(function (arguments) {
    console.log(arguments);
}(1, 2));
```

In effect, the `arguments` object has been overwritten. Is it possible to recover the default `arguments` object inside the function scope?

Comment: No. And since you always have full control of the names of arguments passed to you, there's no need for such a thing.

Comment: @Matt: What if you're injecting code into someone else's function that defined `arguments` as a parameter to prevent you from using it?

Comment: @SLaks then the writer of that function wins.

Comment: @Matt: Yes; I realize that.  I'm providing justification for his question.

Comment: @Randomblue: What scenario are you in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, thinking about it, you *can* do it!

```
(function (arguments) {
    (function () {
       console.log(arguments.callee.caller.arguments);
    })();
})(1, 2);
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AShxf/1/).

Comment: `callee` is deprecated. @ruakh's answer is the way you want to do this.

Comment: Not only is `callee` deprecated, but it currently throws in strict mode. And the same with having a formal parameter named `arguments` as well as trying to access an `arguments` property of a function. So basically, don't do any of this if you care about future proof code.

Comment: +1. (Despite Matt's comment, I don't count my answer as showing how to do what the question asks: the question seems to imply that the function is to be taken as-is. My answer requires a change to the function definition.)

Comment: (Oh, I just realized you're the OP. So obviously you agree. :-) )

Answer (score 3):

Matt, in a comment above, says "no", and I think he's probably right; but you can write something like this:

```
(function f(arguments) {
    console.log(f.arguments);
}(1));
```

(at least in Firefox; I haven't tried other browsers, but I believe this is standard behavior). But if you're not willing to rename your function's argument for some reason, then I'm guessing you're probably not willing to give your function a name, either?

(N.B. The above is still a function expression, not a declaration. You still can't refer to `f` outside itself. It's just that it's no longer an *anonymous* function expression.)

Comment: +1 didn't know functions have an instance variable for `arguments`. Can't imagine that's thread-safe, but oh well, who uses threads in browser JS.

Comment: @Matt: Browser JS doesn't support threads (except for HTML5 web workers)

Comment: @Matt: Re: thread-safety: I really don't know. But it does have seem to have some special scoping rules, at least; something like `(function f(x) { if(x == 1) { f(2); } alert(f.arguments[0]); })(1);` alerts `2` and then `1` (at least in Firefox), so the outer call's `arguments` must get restored when the inner (recursive call) returns? I don't know if that's lexical, or dynamic. There's an MDN page at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/arguments that I'm sure answers these questions, but MDN seems to be down at the moment . . .